# lsp-mode, Hello World in C#

Tags: lsp-mode

I get some weird errors for just the most simple Hello World in C#, with lsp-mode

```
using System;

namespace test
{
    public class Driver
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

On the first line, I get CS8019 Unnecessary using directive and on "Console", I get CS0103 The name Console does not exist in the current context.

However when I run "dotnet run", it runs fine and outputs fine.

Where is the primary location for where to get help with lsp-mode? Is it here?

Also, is there any buffer that outputs these messages from omnisharp, cause I don't even understand how I can copy these messages that are displayed in Emacs.

Comment: How did you configured ```lsp``` - with ```flycheck``` or ```flymake```?

Comment: Neither, it says: "Flymake for csharp is now builtin to csharp-mode.el "